# Use drush 8 in windows

Tags: drupal, window, composer-php, drupal-8, drush

I install drush8 using composer in windows, But I can not use drush 8 because its depends on php posix (http://php.net/manual/en/book.posix.php) which does not have windows dll. Is there any way to install drush 8 on windows ?

[image]

Comment: Friendly advice - go for linux (ubuntu) virtual machine, vagrant even better.

Comment: Try this method URL: https://modulesunraveled.com/drush/installing-drush-windows

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki that is about drush 7, Also there is no problem with installation drush 8, Once we going to run the drush 8 command its has dependency with "posix"

Comment: my bad, use this URL: https://ayesh.me/drush-8-windows-7-8-10